# carry lookahead using structural verilog

Tags: verilog

I am working on 4 bit carry lookahead I am using structural verilog. I am confused as I am instantiating 4 partial full adders what to declare as input and what as wire and where does the sum go? I know this is easy problem for some, but I spent some time trying to find my errors. The way I implement pfa's (partial full adder) I have a,b,carry as input and p(a * b) g(a xor b) as output. Here is where I get confused, what is the carry? Is it input or is it a wire ?
 Below is my code, thank you!

```
module pfa(a,b,c,sum,p,g);  //A one PFA. I need 16 of them5
    //wire w;
    //reg a,b,c;
    //wire sum,p,g;
    input a,b,c;
    output sum,p,g;

    xor (w,a,b);     //repeated P. May need it may not. 
    and (g,a,b);  //Gi
    xor (p,a,b);   //Pi
    xor (sum,w,c);  //sum 
endmodule
                //input    output   
module fourBitPFA(A,B,Cin,P,G,Carry);
    input [3:0] A,B;
    input Cin;
    output [3:0] S;
    output Cout;    
    wire [3:0] P,G,carry;
    wire p0,g0;
    wire b1,b2,b3;
    wire w,w1,w2,w3,w4,w5,w6,w7,w8,w9,w10,w11,w12;
    wire c1,c2,c3,c4;

        pfa PFA0(A[0],B[0],Cin,P[0],G[0],Carry[0]),
            PFA1(A[1],B[1],C[1],P[1],G[1],C[1]),    
            PFA2(A[2],B[2],S[2],P[2],G[2],C[2]),
            PFA3(A[3],B[3],S[3],P[3],G[3],C[3]);
        //propagate
        and (p0,P[3],P[2],P[1],P[0]);

        //GENERATE
        and (w,P[3],G[2]);
        and (w1,P[3],P[2],G[1]);
        and (w2,P[3],P[2],P[1],G[0]);
        or (w,w1,w2);
//CLA 


        and (w3,P[0],Cin);
        or (c1,G[0],w3);
        and (w4,P[1],G[0]);
        and (w5,P[1],P[0],Cin);
        or (c2,G[1],w4,w5);
        and (w6,P[2],G[1]);
        and (w7,P[2],P[1],G[0]);
        and (w8,P[2],P[1],P[0],Cin);
        or (c3,G[2],w6,w7,w8);
        and (w9,P[3],G[2]);
        and (w10,P[3],P[2],G[1]);
        and (w11,P[3],P[2],P[1],G[0]);
        and (w12,P[3],P[2],P[1],P[0],Cin);
        or(c4,w9,w10,w11,w12);
endmodule
```

Answer (score 2):

`wire` elements must be **continuously driven** by something, and **cannot store** a value. Henceforth, they are assigned values using continuous assignment statements.

`reg` can be used to create **registers and other sequential elements** in **procedural blocks**. Thus, it can **store** some value.

`reg` elements can be **used** as **output** within an actual module declaration. But,reg elements **cannot** be **connected** to the **output** port of a module instantiation.

Thus, a reg can drive a wire as RHS of an `assign` statement. On the other way round, a wire can drive a reg in as RHS of a procedural block.

For clear idea about declaration of `reg` or `wire`, refer the image below. By default, input ports are `reg` and output ports are `wire`.

[image: Module connection]

Remember, `wire` can only infer to **combinational logic**, while `reg` can infer to either **combinational or sequential logic**.

Here, in look ahead carry generator, everything is **combinational circuit**. So, declaring `wire` for `sum`, `p` and `g` variables; is feasible.

For `carry`, when two single bit numbers are added in binary, if **both** are `1`'s, then addition results in a two bit number. So, the MSB is considered as `carry`.

**Side Note:** In this case, using *behavioral modelling* may be advantageous from coding point of view.

Also, instiatiating gates requires a gate name. So, use `xor x1(sum,w,c);` where `x1` is the **gate instance name**. This applies to all the gate instances.

Instiatiating single module multiple times requires name of module at every instance name. As follows:

```
    pfa PFA0(A[0],B[0],Cin,P[0],G[0],Carry[0]);
            pfa PFA1(A[1],B[1],C[1],P[1],G[1],C[1]); 
// and so on
```

Comment: Thank you this really helps alot , behavioral modeling is better I agree but my professor wants this in structural

Comment: Structural is okay till you don't get confused in it. Your snippet has gate instance name related issues that's written in my answer.